# Detect another addon from my addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to detect 1 addon which is already present or not.

May i know how can i detect from another addon ?

Or How to detect from the web page if the add on is present or not ?

Thanks,
Madhu H C

Answer (score 4):

You should look at this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager

Comment: This way is the preferred way if he is wanting to check within the same profile. Good point to bring this up.

Answer (score -1):

Located in the profile folder is a file called addons.json this one is updated live on what addons are there. (there is extensions.json but I dont think that updates until browser restart). I might be wrong it might be extensions.json is updated live and addons.json is updated on restart, please share your findings.

This is the path `OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.profileDir, 'addons.json')`

Comment: This method is useful for own profile but mostly it is for other profile. If you want to test for addon in current profile, use the recommended way of AddonManager.jsm as @OndrejDonek has posted.